# How to TRY automounting an external drive in Arch

Tags: boot, mount, arch-linux, raspberry-pi

So I'm trying to setup my own NAS using a Model B Raspberry PI running archlinuxarm and a 500GB external hardrive. In the past I used fstab to automount the drive on boot but I found out that when the drive was not plugged login failed and I could not login into the system.
So I'm looking for a way to, at boot time, mount the drive IF and ONLY IF it is available. Is it possible? Do I need to move away from fstab and into something like udevil?